# How do I get the last four and the first character?

Tags: vbscript

I have this code I want to use to compare two strings. The idea is to get the first letter of a word and the last four of a number and put it together, so that I can compare it to another. For example, if i have "Smith John 123456" and I want to enter "s3456" I should be able to find it.

```
Dim strFileName, strTxtValue

strFileName = "4ABCD_Delta_Jhon_T_JR_123456"
strTxtValue = "D3456"

Dim item, items, firstInitial, lastFour, myArray

strFileName = replace(strFileName,"_"," ")
myArray = Split(strFileName)

For Each item In myArray
    If IsNumeric(item) Then
        lastFour = Right(item, Len(item)-2)
        Exit For
    End If
Next
For Each items In myArray
    firstInitial = Left(items, 1)&lastFour
    If UCase(strTxtValue) = UCase(firstInitial) Then
        Contains = True
    End If
Next
```

So far this is what I have, but I have not be able to make it work. Can somebody please help me?

Comment: The right-most four characters of item is simply, "Right(item, 4)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another alternative:

```
strFileName = "4ABCD_Delta_Jhon_T_JR_123456"
strTxtValue = "D3456"
strFromName = ""
myArray     = Split(strFileName, "_")
For i = 0 To UBound(myArray)
    firstChar = Asc(myArray(i))
    'if not a number...
    If firstChar < 48 Or firstChar > 57 Then
        strFromName = Chr(firstChar)
        Exit For
    End If
Next
strFromName = strFromName & Right(strFileName, 4)
WScript.Echo strFromName, CStr(strFromName = strTxtValue)
'>> D3456 True
```

Comment: this is exactly what i was looking for thank you, and thanks to everybody else you guys rock

Answer (score 2):

Given your first example, getting the first letter and the last four digits is easy:

```
>> s = "Smith John 123456"
>> t = LCase(Left(s, 1)) & Right(s, 4)
>> WScript.Echo t, CStr(t = "s3456")
>>
s3456 True
```

If your input is more diversified, e.g. filenames like "4ABCD_Delta_Jhon_T_JR_123456",
then using a RegExp or a creative use of Split may be necessary. Let's start with:

```
>> s = "4ABCD_Delta_Jhon_T_JR_123456"
>> s = Split(s, "_", 2)(1)
>> t = LCase(Left(s, 1)) & Right(s, 4)
>> WScript.Echo t, CStr(t = "d3456")
>>
d3456 True
>>
```

This obviously depends on the name being the second chunk of the input.

If you provide some more representative samples of your input, I'm willing to think about a RegExp solution.

Comment: thank you ekkehard the problem that i am having is that s could be "4ABCD_Delta_Jhon_T_JR_123456" or this "Delta_Jhon_T_JR_123456"

Answer (score 1):

An alternative would be the use of a regular expression:

```
s = "Smith John 123456"

Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = "^(.).*(.{4})$"

WScript.Echo LCase(re.Replace(s, "$1$2"))
```

and for the second example something like this:

```
s = "4ABCD_Delta_Jhon_T_JR_123456"

Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = "^(?:\w*?[0-9]\w*?_)?([a-z])[a-z]*_.*(.{4})$"
re.IgnoreCase = True

WScript.Echo LCase(re.Replace(s, "$1$2"))
```

Comment: thank you ansgar i try to use regex but the s value can can be this s = "4ABCD_Delta_Jhon_T_JR_123456" or s = "Delta_Jhon_T_JR_123456", so how do you do it